# Java Spring Web application Nullpointer

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm currently trying to create my first Java web application using Spring boot and Spring data.
I wrote a Controller already and now trying to create Datas in an inmemory-database.

I am getting a nullpointer exception when I try to create a new User. Allthough the user has every value set.

POJO:

```
package db;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String userName;

private String email;

private String password;

protected User() {}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

DAO:

```
package db;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Service:

```
package db;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public User start() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setEmail("alovela@uk.com");
        user.setUserName("Ada");
        user.setPassword("Password");

        repository.save(user);

        return user;
    }
}
```

Error when calling UserService.start(); in my main:

```
2017-07-11 20:31:10.027 ERROR 7604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: Add `@Autowired` to UserRepository repository;

Comment: Why is your `User*Service*` which contains a `User*Repository*` annotated with `@Repository`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the NPE was raised on line 
`repository.save(user);`

The dependency `repository` wasn't injected into `UserService`, annotate it with `@Resource` or `@Autowired`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I tried both but I'm still having the same error message. And yeah the error in that line indeed.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add `@Repository` to UserRepository so it will be picked up by component scan feature of Spring

```
 @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

        List<User> findByUserName(String userName);
    }
```

2.Autowire repository in UserService

```
@Autowired
UserRepository repository;`
```

P.S. Not necessary, but suggest to change `@Repository` to `@Service` in UserService class, as it better reflects purpose of this class, and it also Spring to map specific exceptions.

```
@Repository
public class UserService {
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your message. I added the Annotations you suggested. Unfortunately there is still the same error. Also do I need a config file for Spring data? And if yes where can I find an example.

Comment: for which object you are getting NPE?

Comment: In Line: repository.save(user);